# Lyric in this song: 気の思い?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics

There is an Indonesian song with titled "Aishiteru" which is fully in Indonesian language except for one line in Japanese (and a few "a a a aishiteru" lines).

[YouTube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6cHUqP5C_8&feature=player_detailpage#t=158s)

The one line in Japanese starts at 2:38, which I transcribed below but I have difficulty in deciding the part with question marks:

> 君が遠くにいても
>   [ ??? ] がつながるから
>   信じてるよ
>   信じてるよ

At first I thought it was 昨日思い but dismissed it because it's grammatically wrong unless there is a の particle there. So now I'm guessing that it's "ki no omoi", 気の思い, but I have never seen that phrase before and I couldn't find it in dictionaries. What does the phrase mean? Could it be 気の重い instead (also not found in dictionaries)?

Here is the English translation of the stanza that follows after that one line, in case it would help set up the context:

> Even though our bodies are far apart,
>   Our hearts are always near,
>   When you miss me just close your eyes,
>   And think of me.

Any idea anyone?

Comment: Sounds like "君の思いがつながるから" to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's 君【きみ】の想【おも】い, and the み is just sung quickly.

Comment: Probably that right. But I don't think it's pronounced even quickly. The singer is obviously a non-native, and probably made a mistake.

Comment: I suppose it is 君の想い indeed (思い vs 想い?) ... but @sawa, the lead singer of that Indonesian band previously lived in Japan so I assume he's quite knowledgeable in Japanese language.

Comment: @Lukman I see. Then it might be a problem with the edit. There is a slight moment of silence at that moment.